# ajax problems? with activexobjects

Tags: php, ajax, activex

I keep getting the following error's:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://site/cms/js/interface.js :: doAjaxCall :: line 300" data: no]

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://site/cms/js/interface.js :: doAjaxCall :: line 300"  data: no]

Line 0

This is the function with the doAjaxCall

```
function doAjaxCall(cmd,params) {
  var postdata='cmd='+cmd+'&params='+params;

  var a=sajax_init_object();
  if (a) {
    a.open("POST","ajax_handler.php", false);
    a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    a.send(postdata);                      <====Line 300
      document.body.style.cursor="default";

    if(a.readyState == 4) {
      return a.responseText;
    } else {
      alert("We where unable to execute the ajax call.");
    }
  }

function sajax_init_object() {
    var A;
    try {
        A=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            A=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (oc) {
            A=null;
        }
    }
    if(!A && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
        A=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!A)
        alert("Could not create connection object.");
    return A;
}
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Is this going outside of your domain? Are you using a relative url or absolute?

Answer (score 1):

Due to security restrictions in Javascript, it is not possible to retrieve information from remote domains via an XMLHttpRequest.
I think you need a proxy!

Comment: The code uses a relative URI. Where does the remote domain come into this?

Comment: how ever if you have control of the content on the other domain you can allow an AJAX call to it from your site using the security headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` * = wildcard and you can provide a comma list of domains E.G `*.facebook.com,facebook.com`

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the MIME type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

It works in some browsers. It won't work in Gecko based browsers (eg Firefox)

See more details at: [http://ajaxpatterns.org/Talk:XMLHttpRequest_Call](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Talk%3aXMLHttpRequest_Call)